# Ambiguous column name, yet use "." to specify table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, inner-join

When the following query is sent to my database:

```
SELECT statemachines.statemachinename, 
states.statename, 
actionhandlers.actionhandler, 
actions.value, actions.sourcename 
FROM actions, actionhandlers, states, statemachines 
INNER JOIN rules ON (actions.rule_id AND rules.rule_id) 
INNER JOIN actionhandlers ON (actions.actionhandler AND actionhandlers.actionhandler) 
INNER JOIN states ON (states.state_id AND actions.state_id) 
INNER JOIN statemachines ON (states.statemachinename AND statemachines.statemachinename) 
WHERE (rules.eventname = 'PIR') AND (statemachines.currentstate = states.state_id)
```

The following error is returned:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: statemachines.statemachinename (code 1): , while compiling:
```

I have no clue what to do, all my other queries work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify: `FROM actions, actionhandlers, states, statemachines` => `FROM actions`

Answer (score 4):

You use `statemachines` twice. Once in the JOIN clause and once in the FROM.

Name one of them:

```
...
FROM actions, actionhandlers, states, statemachines AS statemachines1
...
```

Comment: Does it not recognise that it is the same statemachines, can I just delete the statemachines in my from clause?

Comment: I think I understand now, I only need to declare one table in the from, and the others get discovered as they get lumped on (by the inner joins)